# Return a hyper::Body of serde:Value

Tags: rust, serde, hyper

In my situation, my function can only have signature:

```
pub async fn do_something(mut req: Request<Body>) -> Result<Response<Body>, CustomError> {
  .....
}
```

I know how to return a body of string in my function as follow:

```
Ok(Response::new(Body::from("some string".to_string())))
```

However, something like this does not work with serde::Value; it only worked with strings.

What is the proper way to return a serde::Value while maintaining the same method signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize into [`BytesMut`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.BytesMut.html) from the [`bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes) crate, then convert into into `Body`:

```rust
use bytes::{BufMut, BytesMut};

let mut buf = BytesMut::new().writer();
serde_json::to_writer(&mut buf, &value)
    .expect("serialization of `serde_json::Value` into `BytesMut` cannot fail");
Ok(Response::new(Body::from(buf.into_inner().freeze())))
```

If you can afford something less performant, you can serialize into `Vec`:

```rust
Ok(Response::new(Body::from(
    serde_json::to_vec(&value).expect("serialization of `serde_json::Value` into `Vec` cannot fail"),
)))
```

Comment: Why would `to_vec` be less performant?

Comment: @Caesar Because it allocates twice: first for the serialization and then [in the conversion to `Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/src/bytes/bytes.rs.html#808-813) (`into_boxed_slice()`).

Comment: Ah, because it needs to `shink_to_fit`.